# internationalization plugin Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, internationalization

I have a small Question regarding Eclipse Internationalization plugin ..
which is described here

```
    https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/wbpro/features/internationalization
```

I am able to add the different locales/ languages ..

What i want to know is , Will i have to translate everything myself , or eclipse will do the translation itself,

So if i added 10 languages and each language have 100 words,will i have to find the translation of these 100 words for the 10 languages my self and put them in properties files , or is there any other easy way??

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Automatic machine translation still leads to very low quality translations nowadays. So independent of Eclipse or any other tool, the localization of programs is almost always done by actual human beings. Otherwise the resulting product has a bad usability.